# Valgrind: How to force it to generate heap summary without terminating process?

Tags: valgrind

When using Valgrind, I noticed that it only generates the Heap Summary when the process is terminating. Is there a way to force Valgrind to scan the memory and print leak reports when process is still running?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to the `VALGRIND_DO_LEAK_CHECK` [client request](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.clientreqs), you can also run valgrind with `--vgdb=yes` to enable embedded [gdbserver](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver), and then issue `monitor leak_check full reachable any` [command](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver-commandhandling) at the `(gdb)` prompt.

This doesn't require modifying and rebuilding the target program, and has other advantages: you can set breakpoints and perform leak checks at arbitrary points in the execution, not just the ones where you've put in the client request.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `VALGRIND_DO_LEAK_CHECK` client request from `valgrind/memcheck.h`.