# How tu use Valgrind to get leak summary for a process runs continuously?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-leaks, heap-memory, valgrind

I am working in Linux environment (RDKB stack) for an embedded device

I am trying to fix memory leak issues as i could see a process whose virtual memory and the RAM usage (VSZ and RSS from top command) keeps increasing constantly and the device gets rebooted after memory gets depleted. Also, my process is continuous and it wont be terminated automatically once it gets started.

The most possible cause for this could be the memory allocated over heap was missed to be freed, I am trying to debug via valgrind.

Is there a way i could get the leak summary via Valgrind when the process is not gracefully exited, as when i kill the process binded with Valgrind abruptly,i am not getting the total heap summary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500541/valgrind-how-to-force-it-to-generate-heap-summary-without-terminating-process

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Valgrind: How to force it to generate heap summary without terminating process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500541/valgrind-how-to-force-it-to-generate-heap-summary-without-terminating-process)

Comment: @PaulFloyd, yes, but im searching how to send VALGRIND_DO_LEAK_CHECK to valgrind in runtime

Comment: The macro needs to be compiled into your executable (which means you need to rebuild it). That's why the top answer recommends using vgdb, which doesn't require you to rebuild.

Comment: I've edited the first answer to add a link to the Valgrind manual for client requests.

Comment: Make a branch in version control for leak testing. Change the implementation so that it does not run continuously but e.g. for 5 minutes. Don't merge the branch to main.